# How to know which ERC20 tokens a wallet owns?

Tags: web3js, etherscan

On Etherscan, when you view the details for a particular address, you can see a list of ERC20 tokens which are owned by that address:
[image: Token Balances]

How does Etherscan do this? It is my understanding that you have to call a function on each ERC20 contract to see the balance for a particular address. Is there some function in web3 that provides this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct about the function, the [ERC20 standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md) defines a function which all ERC20 compatible tokens *must* include as follows:

```
function balanceOf(address _owner) view returns (uint256 balance)
```

Calling this function on a particular token contract, for a particular address, will return how many of those tokens this particular address owns.

How does Etherscan know *all* the different tokens you have? I don't know for sure, but as the name of their website suggests, their system watches the blockchain, and sorts the data into a readable format (ie, the website).
So presumably whenever a contract gets deployed, their system checks it to ask "is this an ERC20 token contract?" and if so, it takes note of that.

Remember that the blockchain is basically just a big database, so when you enter a wallet address it could just call `balanceOf` on all the different ERC20 tokens it knows about, with your address, against its own copy of the blockchain, and display the ones that return greater than 0.

(Note: for efficiency they may actually just watch for changes and store all *relevant* data on their own private backend database - but the end result is the same).

To answer the final part of your question, using Web3, if we assume `token` is your ERC20 token contract, you can get balances as follows:

```
const balance = await token.methods.balanceOf(someAddress).call();
```

Comment: isn't this `balanceOf` function returns the balance of that account token owner?

`//Get the token balance for account tokenOwner`. this is what written on it.